# Scrapy log in form

Tags: python, forms, web, scrapy

I'm trying to automate a log in form via scrapy using the formrequest method. However, the site that I am using does not use a simple HTML form "fieldset" contianing different "divs" (two of them are the username and password). I want to target those fields and input my own text. Here is what I have after looking at the documentation

```
import scrapy
from loginform import fill_login_form
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class PollSpider(scrapy.Spider):


genres = [""]
login_user = "drexel"
login_pass = "dragons"
name = "poll"
start_urls = ["http://www.pollstarpro.com/home"]


def parse(self, response): 

    divs = response.xpath('//div')
    for inp in divs.xpath('input'):
        print(inp)      #Typo

    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname='fieldset',
        formdata={'ctl11$userNameText': 'drexel', 'ctl11$passwordText': 'fuck'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )
def after_login(self, response):
    if "Invalid" in response.body:
        print("fucked up")
    else:
        print("success!")
    #scrape away!
```

Not only does this not work but also my console is printing "success" even though the password entered is incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is  `print(in)p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue comes from body attribute. Try this.
There were also a few bugs that I fixed

```
import scrapy
from loginform import fill_login_form
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector  #FIXED

class PollSpider(scrapy.Spider):


genres = [""]
login_user = "drexel"
login_pass = "dragons"
name = "poll"
start_urls = ["http://www.pollstarpro.com/home"]


def parse(self, response): 
    s = Selector(response) #FIXED
    for inp in s.xpath('//div/input'): #REFACTORED
        print(in)

    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formname='fieldset',
        formdata={'ctl11$userNameText': 'drexel', 'ctl11$passwordText': 'fuck'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )
def after_login(self, response):
    if u"Invalid" in response.body_as_unicode():
        print("failed")
    else:
        print("success!")
    #scrape away!
```